# regex: get numbered capture of all numbers in a string

Tags: regex, autohotkey

How can capture all the numbers in a given string?  It shouldn't matter whether they are floating point numbers, integers, positive or negative.  It should capture 50 or 100.25 or 12345678 or -78.999 each as a numbered capture.

My intent is to find and replace nth number in a string (autohotkey).

The regex should capture ALL the matches into an array.

So far, I've come up with this regex (which only seems to capture the first match):

```
[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Here is my autohotkey function, if you be interested:

```
ReplaceNumber(whattext, instance, replacewith){
    numpos := regexmatch(whattext, "Ox)[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?", thisnumber)
    returnthis := thisnumber.value(instance)
    return returnthis
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polyethene's [grep](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/14817-grep-global-regular-expression-match/) function, you can give it a regex string, and it will return a delimited string of all the matches.  Then you can replace that exact instance of the number with your string.  In [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/51704-re-regexmatch-why-is-it-not-finding-all-the-subpatterns/)(thanks to HamZa DzCyberDeV), there is an explanation of why this is.

(You need the [grep script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/14817-grep-global-regular-expression-match/) for this!)

```
ReplaceNumber(whattext, instance, replacewith){
    numpos := grep(whattext, "[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",thisnumber,1,0,"|")
    stringsplit, numpos, numpos,|
    stringsplit, thisnumber,thisnumber,|

    thispos := numpos%instance%   ;get the position of the capture
    thisinstance := thisnumber%instance%  ;get the capture itself
    thislen := strlen(thisinstance) 
    ;now fetch the string that comes before the named instance
    leftstring := substr(whattext, 1, thispos-1)
    rightstring := substr(whattext, thispos+thislen, strlen(whattext))

    returnthis := leftstring . replacewith . rightstring

    return returnthis
}
msgbox, % replacenumber("7 men swap 55.2 or 55.2 for 100 and -100.", 5, "SWAPPED")
```

Results:

```
; 1-->  SWAPPED men swap 55.2 for 100 and -100.
; 2-->  7 men swap SWAPPED or 55.2 for 100 and -100.
; 3 --> 7 men swap 55.2 or SWAPPED for 100 and -100.
; 4 --> 7 men swap 55.2 or 55.2 for SWAPPED and -100.
; 5 --> 7 men swap 55.2 or 55.2 for 100 and SWAPPED.
```

Thanks, polyethene and hamza!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [AutoHotKey uses PCRE](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm), so the following regex should do the job:

`[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: That matches, but I'm not sure that it is a *numbered* capture.  It matches three times, but does not capture three times, and so only the first match gets returned.

Comment: @BGM I'm not familiar with autohotkey, but i found [this post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/51704-re-regexmatch-why-is-it-not-finding-all-the-subpatterns/) and it looks like it's the same problem you have, apparently you have to do a certain loop.

Comment: Hamza, I am already doing a loop line by line.  I could loop the entire thing and test to see whether each character is a number, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Hamza, that link you posted in your last comment had the answer - there was a post there where polyethene wrote a short grep function.  That function, when given the regex from my original post, will return a delimited string of all the numbers in the string: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/14817-grep-global-regular-expression-match/  Since you led me to the right place, I'm going to mark your answer, but I'll post the solution myself.

Comment: @BGM no, i think you should answer and mark it as an answer for other visitors !